# Flutter Slide Animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm working on an application which requires me to perform a left-to-right slide animation with the "current" widget being the source and the destination which gets animated to.

The animation should provide an affect like an iOS native slide to go back animation.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a gif image for the slide animation you are looking for?

Comment: Couldn't get a gif done but jotted the idea down in an image. Let me know if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official tutorial for Page Transitions.
Check the link below, it has the perfect example you are looking for:

[Slide Animation between Screens](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not looking for Page Transitions. I need to animate my current screen with a slide animation with the destination also being the current screen. Check the image I have attached to the question. Thanks again.